# AttributeError: 'Search' object has no attribute 'execute_suggest'

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Here is my code:

```
class SearchSuggest(View):
    def get(self, request):
        key_words = request.GET.get('s', '')
        re_datas = []
        if key_words:
            s = ArticleType.search()
            s = s.suggest('my_suggest', key_words, completion={
                "field": "suggest", "fuzzy": {
                "fuzziness": 1
                },
                "size": 5
            })
            suggestions = s.execute_suggest()
            for match in suggestions.my_suggest[0].options:
                source = match._source
                re_datas.append(source["title"])
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(re_datas),

    content_type="application/json")
```

It's a piece of code in views in django.when I run this project.It raise:

```
File "/home/yixuan/PycharmProjects/Scrapy/LcvSearch/search/views.py", line 20, in get
suggestions = s.execute_suggest()
AttributeError: 'Search' object has no attribute 'execute_suggest'
```

I don't know where is error. I will appreciate it if you can solve it.

my version is:

- elasticsearch-dsl==6.1.0
- elasticsearch==6.2.0

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch-dsl-py do you have ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like elasticsearch-dsl has removed the function `execute_suggest` from their `Search` object. Had to check the source code for this, since it appears it hasn't been documented in their changelogs or releases.

I assume you can just use `execute` and parse the response according to your needs, but just in case, here is the source code for `execute_suggest`, if you want to implement it someway yourself.

```
def execute_suggest(self):
    es = connections.get_connection(self._using)
        return SuggestResponse(
            es.suggest(
                index=self._index,
                body=self._suggest,
                **self._params
            )
        )
```

`SuggestResponse` is just an `AttrDict` it appears.

Source:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/6.1.0/elasticsearch_dsl/search.py
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/5.4.0/elasticsearch_dsl/search.py

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

check your elasticsearch-dsl version  #elasticsearch-dsl --version

## Elasticsearch 6.x

elasticsearch-dsl>=6.0.0,<7.0.0

## Elasticsearch 5.x

elasticsearch-dsl>=5.0.0,<6.0.0

## Elasticsearch 2.x

elasticsearch-dsl>=2.0.0,<3.0.0